# I'm having an issue running a query from a batch file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, batch-file, command-line

So I'm trying to run a query from a batch file and I can't figure out why its not working
(I'm going to edit out sensative information)

```
sqlcmd -S [server name] -i "[path name for query.sql]"
```

when I run the batch file i get this message at the end

```
sqlcmd -S [server name] -i "[path name for query.sql]" 'sqlcmd' is not 
recognized as an internal or external command
```

so any ideas whats up?

Comment: You need to either have the path for "sqlcmd" in your path or run it from the directory where it is located.

Comment: This is what it looks like

"\\network\folder1\folder2\folder3\queryfile.sql"

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/803219/sqlcmd-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: Ali i'm not sure that's relevant to what I want to do because they're using a version of SQL that doesn't have the sqlcmd function

Comment: So I'm thinking that part of the problem might be that the sql query file and the batch file are on a seperate network. Could it be a problem if files are not locally found on the computer?

For even more clarity, I'm remote logging into a testing computer to run these batch files and queries that are on a local network accessible by all computers in the area.

Comment: Further, when I try to get to the network using the command window on my computer by using

    pushd \\network

It tells me the network path could not be found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use your batch script in the same way, without specifying full path to sqlcmd, you need to add a full path to sqlcmd to env variable %PATH% on your machine. Or just specify full path to sqlcmd in batch script

Comment: I thought I had a full path, is there something I'm missing

Comment: You miss full path to sqlcmd.exe.